# Does an official real-time 3D graphics interface exist for Java, if so what is it?

Tags: java, opengl, 3d

I've Googled for it and it looks as if Java OpenGL wrappers are either community projects, or are discontinued or both.

Is there an official, or any number of official 3D interfaces to use for Java?

This isn't asking in general for a recommendation, so it seeks a factual answer.

Thanks.

Comment: JavaFX has support for 3-D rendering, such as [3-D shapes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape3D.html), [lighting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/LightBase.html), and a [camera](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#cameraProperty).

Comment: Use lwjgl. Its basically OpenGL in java but there are a lot of other bindings comes with it like GLFW, OpengAL, Assimp, NanoVG and so on. And it works very nicely.